# Xdebug not as zend extension IIS7

Tags: iis, xdebug, php-ini

I can't get `xdebug` loaded as `Zend` extension, because the `php.ini` automatically puts in the wrong term.

The message in `phpinfo()` is

> XDEBUG NOT LOADED AS ZEND EXTENSION

I'm Using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
PHP 5.3.8
Zend Engine v2.3.0

My part of `php.ini`:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

No errors logged.

I need to activate every extension in IIS settings. When I then restart IIS, `php.ini` is updated with the line

```
[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.0-5.3-VC9-NTS]
extension=php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
```

Why this?

Comment: I had to disable the php extension by commenting out extension=php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts.dll.  After restarting IIS, phpinfo showed xdebug running as a zend extension.  pasting the phpinfo into http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php verified everything was running correctly.

Comment: Please add the comment as an answer and mark this question as "Answered"

Answer (score 0):

(Solved by the OP and answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> It now works after changing the extension path to absolute. The 2 lines were added anyway, but `phpinfo()` now shows the full xdebug config.

Working part of `php.ini`:

```
[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.0-5.3-VC9-NTS]
zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.0-5.3-VC9-NTS]
extension=php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
```